# Run a database migration command when deploying a Docker container to AWS

Tags: php, symfony, docker, amazon-ec2, doctrine-migrations

Please bear with me. Pretty new to Docker.

I'm deploying Docker containers (detached) to an AWS EC2 registry using [CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/). On deploy, the following command is run after setting some environmental variables etc:

```
exec docker run -d ${PORTS} -v cache-${CACHE_VOLUME} --env-file $(dirname $0)/docker.env --tty "${IMAGE}:${TAG}"
```

The container runs an image located and tagged in EC2 Container Service. No problems so far.

Since this is a PHP application (specifically a Symfony2 application) I would normally need to issue the following command to execute database migrations on deployment:

```
 php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
```

Now, is there any to run this command during "docker run..." while keeping the container running, or do I need to run another container specifically for this command?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint). This script runs at the container startup.

entrypoint.sh file:

```
# create or update db
./wait-for-it.sh <DB_HOST>:<DB_PORT> -t 30
php app/console doctrine:migrations:execute 

# start apache
apache2-foreground
```

[wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) is a script that waits until the database is started.

Answer (score 8):

Just leaving this here for the next one that searches for this... ;-)

When using a recent version of Doctrine, there is a pretty handy parameter for this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --allow-no-migration
```

The "allow-no-migration" parameter instructs doctrine not to throw an exception, when there is nothing to do...

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I do as follows:

```
docker-compose exec [containerID] ./app/console migrations:migrate --no-interaction
```

Comment: But how can the deployment script know the [containerId]? Or are you running it manually?

Comment: I do it manually. But i think u could do a "docker ps" in your deployment-script and grep the containerId you would apply to...

Comment: This mixes two possible solutions. `docker-compose run [service]` would spin up a new docker container. You can also use `docker ps` to find out the container id of the running php container and use `docker exec [containerID] [migrationCommand]` to run the command inside the running container instead of spinning up a new one.

Comment: @mr.void but you can't do using Swarm mode